# All five-card boards avoiding redundant suit combinations

Tags: combinatorics, card-games

I'm looking to narrow a space of all 5-card boards in Texas Hold'em.
For context, in Texas Hold'em we have a max of five dealt community cards, where the first three are dealt in one shot, then the fourth and lastly the fifth. Five cards dealt in this way, where the order of the first three cards is irrelevant but it matters which cards were the fourth and fifth, are called a "board". There are

$${52 \choose 3 }\cdot 49\cdot 48$$

such boards, about 52 million.

Now, a bit of notation. In cards we use two characters to represent each card, the first character is the index, and the second is the suit. For example `Ah` is the Ace of hearts, `5c` is the 5 of clubs.

I am looking for an algorithm to create all possible 5-card boards, but removing the redundant suit combination swaps - I consider `Ah, Kh, 9d, 5c, 4s` the same as `As, Ks, 9c, 5d, 4h` the same as `Ac, Kc, 9d, 5s, 4h` and so on, we can consider all of the mas `Ax, Kx, 9y, 5z, 4w` where `x` `y` `z` and `w` can be any suit.

Can you help me come up with the most efficient algorithm? The only algo I have now, looking for all the boards and then removing the duplicates, which is not very efficient.

Comment: You should note Ax,Kx,9y|5z|4w for example, so we are sure that flop/turn/river are separate ; Ax,Kx,9y|5z|4w is not the same as Ax,Kx,5z|9y|4w.  You could also consider that starting with Ax,Ky,9z|5w , there is no risk of color, so the last card can be from any suit (same as King or same as Ace or... , it is similar) so Ax,Ky,9z|5w|4x = Ax,Ky,9z|5w|4y . But I add complexity to a problem which is already complex.

Comment: For an algorithm, start step by step. What is the algorithm to generate all flops.  We can have no pair, 1 pair, or 1 brelan. Generate all brelans is simple. If you have a pair King+ Ace, from 3 different suits, you have to decide if you will code this as Kx,Ky,Az, or Ax,Ky,Kz. I suggest 1st convention. If you have no pair, and 2 cards from the same suit, you have also to decide if you will code this as 7x,6x,8y or 8x,7y,6y.  I have no preference, but it may impact how you will build your algorithm.

Comment: If you ave no pair, and 3 card from 3 different suits, your 1st message suggests you will say the higest card is from suit x, the middle from suit y, and the lowest from suit z. I think there is no complexity to do this, as soon as you have decided those missing conventions.

Comment: One more point. You want to generate all possible flops+turns+river, But they don't have same probability. Flop Ax,Kx,Qx corresponds to 4 possibilities, and Flop Ax,Ky,Qz corresponds to 24 possibilities. If you just create a catalog of all possible Flops, with no 'Count' associate to each flop, you miss something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’d start by generating all possible “$5$-rank boards”, i.e. all combinations of $5$ ranks with the relevant order distinctions, regardless of suits. You can easily do that by allowing all five cards to be of any rank (that’s $\binom{13+3-1}3=455$ possibilities for the flop and $13$ each for the turn and river, so $455\cdot13\cdot13=76895$ in all) and then removing the $13$ impossible boards with $5$ identical ranks, for a total of $76895-13=76882$ possible $5$-rank boards.

Then you can assign suits `w`, `x`, `y`, `z` to them as follows. For each $5$-rank board, go through the ranks one by one and to each rank assign all suits allowed under the following rules:

- The suit must be lower than any equivalent suit, where two suits are equivalent if they’ve been assigned to the same set of ranks in the flop and neither has been assigned to the turn.
- The suit must be different from any suit assigned to the same rank so far.
- Within the flop, the suit must be higher than any suit assigned to the same rank so far.

For example, for the board `A`, `3`, `3`, `2`, `A`, starting at the front, the `A` is assigned `w`. Then the `3` can either be assigned `w` or `x`. If `w`, then the next `3` must be `x`, and if `x`, then the next `3` must be `y`. The `2` can be any suit at most one higher than the ones already assigned, except if the `3`s are `x` and `y` it can’t be `y` (because that’s equivalent to `x`), and the same for the `A` except it can’t be `w` again and it can be `y` if `x` has been assigned to the `2` (because then it’s no longer equivalent). That yields a total of $14$ possibilities:

```
Aw, 3w, 3x, 2w, Ax
Aw, 3w, 3x, 2w, Ay
Aw, 3w, 3x, 2x, Ax
Aw, 3w, 3x, 2x, Ay
Aw, 3w, 3x, 2y, Ax
Aw, 3w, 3x, 2y, Ay
Aw, 3w, 3x, 2y, Az
Aw, 3x, 3y, 2w, Ax
Aw, 3x, 3y, 2w, Az
Aw, 3x, 3y, 2x, Ax
Aw, 3x, 3y, 2x, Ay
Aw, 3x, 3y, 2x, Az
Aw, 3x, 3y, 2z, Ax
Aw, 3x, 3y, 2z, Az
```

[Here’s Java code](https://github.com/joriki/math/blob/master/info/joriki/math/stackexchange/Question4643411.java) that performs this algorithm and checks that it results in the same number $2554656$ of inequivalent boards as the inefficient algorithm you described. (In fact I didn’t wait for the inefficient algorithm to complete for $13$ ranks; I checked the validity by performing the comparison for up to $9$ ranks.)

Comment: I'm going over the implementation, why is the flop made of permutations and not combinations? there is no meaning to the order of the 3 cards in the flop

might take me some time to figure this code, I'm a Pythonista, so bear with me :)

Comment: @bluesummers: Only one of the permutations for each combination is ever generated. You can see this in line $67$, where the rank doesn't decrease within the flop, in line $82$, where the suit increases within the flop, and in line $116$, where the card (rank and suit combined) increases within the flop. You can check that the code generates the same number of inequivalent boards as your own implementation of your inefficient algorithm – in case that can't handle $13$ ranks, you can reduce `nranks` to check a case it can handle. (The imported class `Permutations` is in the same repository.)

Comment: I tried to replicate this in Python, but I got a total of 2556528 5 cards boards. Can you try to help me? For 3 card boards (flop only, remember, in flop order does not matter) I got 1755, for 4-card boards, I got 63193 - maybe using those figures you might be able to fish out where did I go wrong

Comment: @bluesummers: I get those same numbers if I set `ncards` to $3$ or $4$ in my code. If you link to the Python code, I can take a look at it.

Comment: Here it is, it is nothing like your code, but I tried to replicate the thought process behind it

https://gist.github.com/eliorc/853b7d312d400385a626637d7c87c4ee

Comment: @bluesummers: The problem seems to be in the choice of suits for the river. As far as I can tell, it's in this line: `elif len(suits) > 1 and len(flop_assigned_suits) == min(assignment_index,3) and turn_suit not in suits: excluded_suits.update(suits[1:])`

I'm not sure how that's supposed to work, but I get both `['2w', '2x', '2y', 'Aw', 'Ax']` and `['2w', '2x', '2y', 'Aw', 'Ay']` in the output; those are equivalent and the second one shouldn't be generated.

Comment: @bluesummers: The rule in the answer that excludes this is "The suit must be lower than any equivalent suit, where two suits are equivalent if they’ve been assigned to the same set of ranks in the flop and neither has been assigned to the turn". In my code, this is implemented in lines $85$ to $88$.

Comment: I'll take a look and try to figure it out

Comment: @joriko thanks a lot, the error was exactly there. Got it to work now.